# IBM MQ Topic Default Message Retention

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there any default retention period for messages on MQ Topic. In case consumer/client is not putting Expiry in MQ Header.

Comment: topics themselves do not hold messages with the exception of publishers that indicate that want the publish to be a retained publication, and even then only the last published message is retained.  Subscriptions can be durable which means if the consumer disconnects messages published while they are disconnected will accumulate.  The publisher can set a expiry time on the published messages.

Comment: If a subscription is durable then it will be retained for how long?
We are concerned with memory consumption rightnow.

Comment: Messages published to durable subscribers that are not connected will live forever unless the publisher sets expiry or in MQ v8 and higher you could look to set CAPEXPRY either on a topic object or on subscribed queues to force an expiry.  Note this is not the same thing as a retained publication.   Also messages waiting for a subscriber to connect and consume will be written to disk and won't stay in memory, storage is the concern not memory.

Comment: If you can click edit and put some more details to clarify exactly what you are asking, I'll try to put more detail in a actual answer.

Comment: Resolved with CAPEXPIRY property, we wanted to have default expriry for Topic messages in case publisher is not setting any expiry.